# srcset в css не работает

Tags: html5, css3

Вообще ни в какую не работает ни в одном браузере. В чем может быть проблема?

```
background-image: -webkit-image-set(
        url("../img/bg-header(sml).jpg") 400w,
        url('../img/bg-header(med).jpg') 700w,
        url('../img/bg-header(lrg).jpg') 1100w);
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [тест на поддержку вашим браузером](http://cloudfour.com/examples/image-set/) свойства image-set. Там же можно и пример использования посмотреть.
[Полный список](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set) поддерживаемых браузеров.

Возможно, вам нужны [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) для указания, какое изображение подгружать в зависимости от ширины экрана?

Comment: О поддержке браузерами знаю, смотрел
Просто хотелось бы именно таким способом, да и узнать почему оно не работает)

Comment: Давайте по порядку:)  1. Image specifiers consist of an asset reference and a scale factor: image-set( imagespec [ ',' imagespec ]* ), где imagespec ::= <image> S {num} 'x'. Только масштабирование работает. 2. Вы хотите написать стили, которые будут работать исключительно в браузерах на движке -webkit-?

Comment: Ох, даже не знаю где я вычитал о том, что можно записывать в таком варианте (400w), спасибо за поправку :) А стили я хочу написать для всех браузеров, префикс -webkit- лишь для примера